# Convex function derivatives inequality

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, convex-analysis

Decide whether there exists function $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,+\infty)$  such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f''(x)f(x)>(f'(x))^{2}$.

I know that if such function would exist then $f''(x) >0$ for all $x$ so such function would be convex. I was hoping that I could fix $a$ and find some solutions to $f''f=a(f')^2$ but all solutions of that are not nonnegative or have problems with continiuity at $x=0$.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I would start by dividing both sides by $f$ and $f'$ then repackaging both sides as single derivatives.

Comment: So does $f$ have to approach $0$ at some point even if it is $-\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We observe that
$$\frac{f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2}{f^2(x)} = \left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)' =\left(\ln(f(x))\right)''$$

So, it suffices to chose $f$ such that $\ln(f(x))$ is a convex function. For example, if we choose $\ln(f(x)) = x^2$ then
$$f(x) = e^{x^2}$$